# Android onTouch event not working in Galaxy S3

Tags: android

I am working on an android application in which I override the onTouchEvent of the activity and opens a new activity when the screen is pressed.
It is working perfectly fine on Google Nexus S(upgraded to Android 4.0.4) and Samsung Galaxy S2(2.3.4).
But when I run the application on Samsung Galaxy S3,I cannot move to the next step when the screen is touched.
Is there any difference in touch event handling of S3?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        break; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
        break; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), screen3.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);
        break; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: is it only the drag gesture that does not work or when you release the the finger the object changes its position?

Comment: please post onTouch code

Comment: Following is override touch event code :public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {   
     switch (event.getAction()) 
        {                  
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:      
          break;                 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          break;  
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), screen3.class);
          
                startActivity(mIntent);break;              
         }            
         return true;         
    }

Comment: Why don't you set an `onClickListener()` on your main view if the activity?